# update magento currency rates using custom php file

Tags: magento, module

I'm trying to use a custom file to update currency rates using cURL from my local bank and insert the data into the currency database table. Do I have to create a module to do that, or can I do that without creating a module? I intend to use cron too. Does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this, and are there any tutorials?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Best way to create custom mangento api as changing currency rates is not implemented in default magento api. Here is a simple tutorial that you can follow to implement the custom api
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/custom-api